# remove objects from array that satisfying the condition in elastic search with javascript api

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Suppose I have a array type field in my document of elastic search, like below:-

```
"prog_lists": [
 {
  "description": "engineer",
  "age": 25,
  "name": "ashu"
 },
 {
  "description": "programmer",
  "age": 26,
  "name": "rajit"
 },
 {
  "description": "designer",
  "age": 27,
  "name": "naveen"
 }
]
```

I want to remove objects which have name equals to ashu, or remove multiple object which satisfy the query like whose age is greater then 25

I am able to do this by specifying all the things within  object like below:-

```
client.update({
        "index": "daffo_netgear",
        "type": "array",
        "id": "2201",
        "body": {
            "script":"ctx._source.prog_lists.remove(list)",
            "params" : {
                    "list" :{
                        "description": "engineer",
                        "age": 25,
                        "name": "ashu"
                     }
             }
        }})
```

but i want to do this just specifying name or age

```
client.update({
        "index": "daffo_netgear",
        "type": "array",
        "id": "2201",
        "body": {
            "script":"ctx._source.prog_lists.remove(list)",
            "params" : {
                    "list" :{
                          "name": "ashu"
                     }
             }
        }})
```

My node module elastic search version is 2.4.2 elastic search server is 1.3.2.

Answer (score 2):

**I have got my answer, and its solution is**

```
POST /twitter/twit/1/_update

{
  "script": "item_to_remove = nil; foreach (item : ctx._source.list) { if (item['tweet_id'] == tweet_id) { item_to_remove=item; } } if (item_to_remove != nil) ctx._source.list.remove(item_to_remove);",
  "params": {"tweet_id": "123"}
}
```

**if you have more than one item that matches the criteria, use a list instead:**

```
POST /twitter/twit/1/_update
{
  "script": "items_to_remove = []; foreach (item : ctx._source.list) { if (item['tweet_id'] == tweet_id) { items_to_remove.add(item); } } foreach (item : items_to_remove) {ctx._source.list.remove(item);}",
  "params": {"tweet_id": "123"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If someone still needs this in 2021, then here is the working version for ES 7:**

```
POST /users/_update/1
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.my_objects.length; ++i) {if (ctx._source.my_objects[i]['name'] == params['name']) {ctx._source.my_objects.remove(i);}}",
        "params": {"name": "delete_this"}
    }
}
```