# Elasticsearch remove a field from an object of an array in a dynamically generated index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to delete fields from an object of an array in Elasticsearch. The index has been dynamically generated.

This is the mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "result": {
          "properties": {
            "resultid": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "resultname": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

this is a document:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "resultid": 69,
            "resultname": "SFO"
        },
        {
            "resultid": 151,
            "resultname": "NYC"
        }
    ],
    "age": 54,
    "name": "Jorge",
    "timestamp": "2020-04-02T16:07:47.292000"
}
```

My goals is to remove all the fields resultid in result in all the document of the index. After update the document should look like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "resultname": "SFO"
        },
        {
            "resultname": "NYC"
        }
    ],
    "age": 54,
    "name": "Jorge",
    "timestamp": "2020-04-02T16:07:47.292000"
}
```

I tried using the following articles on stackoverflow but with no luck:
[Remove elements/objects From Array in ElasticSearch Followed by Matching Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384199/remove-elements-objects-from-array-in-elasticsearch-followed-by-matching-query)
[remove objects from array that satisfying the condition in elastic search with javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232731/remove-objects-from-array-that-satisfying-the-condition-in-elastic-search-with-j)
[Delete nested array in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148466/delete-nested-array-in-elasticsearch)
[Removing objects from nested fields in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739683/removing-objects-from-nested-fields-in-elasticsearch)

Hopefully someone can help me find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reindex your index in a new one with [_reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) and call a script to remove your fields :

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index-reindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
     for (int i=0;i<ctx._source.result.length;i++) {
        ctx._source.result[i].remove("resultid")
     }
     """

  }
}
```

After you can delete your first index :

```
DELETE my-index
```

And reindex it :

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-reindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-index"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your script with an "update by query" so that I don't have reindex

Comment: Perfect ! it's just safer to reindex in a new index. Can you mark my answer as resolved

Comment: I agree that it is safer to reindex to a new index, so that if something goes wrong you'll always have your old index.

Answer (score 1):

I combined the answer from Luc E with some of my own knowledge in order to reach a solution without reindexing.

```
POST INDEXNAME/TYPE/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false&conflicts=proceed
```

```
{
"script": {
    "source": "for (int i=0;i<ctx._source.result.length;i++) { ctx._source.result[i].remove(\"resultid\")}"
    },
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "result.id"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks again Luc!

Answer (score 1):

If your array has more than one copy of element you want to remove. Use this:
`ctx._source.some_array.removeIf(tag -> tag == params['c'])`